# Articles/email/letters review

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions

What is the best place where the community can review my article/letter for errors or increasing the quality? Or can I post my letter on the main site for review?

Comment: Proof-reading is explicitly off-topic, so the answer to the secondary question is "No" -- but thanks for asking first! Others may be able to provide suggestions as to where proof-reading is accepted.

Comment: I've heard that [lang-8](http://lang-8.com) is a good site for this type of thing.